# Authenticating Jenkins through JSON API using password

Tags: authentication, jenkins

I am trying to build a frontend that for certain functionality needs to communicate with a Jenkins backend. In my frontend I want the user to be able to log in with the Jenkins credentials (username and password, using Kerberos) and have these passed to my Jenkins server, upon which I'd like to retrieve the token that can be used to make further API calls to the Jenkins server without disclosing the password in each request.

I know that to be able to make Jenkins API calls I need to use HTTP Basic auth, and it will accept both `user:token` and `user:password`. I want to avoid sending the password in each request though.

I also know that I can find my token by going to the Jenkins webpage, log in with my password, go to my profile page and find the token there. I can then base64 encode that into a functioning HTTP basic authentication header. This works fine.

However, I can't seem to find a decent way to programmatically authenticate using the password, trading the password for the token. The best I've been able to accomplish is to do a GET to said profile page at `https://<JENKINS_HOST>/me/configure` using the `user:password` basic auth header and then parse the resulting HTML for the api token, which obviously doesn't feel very robust:

```
$ curl -v --silent https://<USER:PASS@JENKINS_HOST>/me/configure 2>1
    | sed -n 's/.*apiToken" value="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'

<TOKEN>
```

What I expected/hoped to find was an API endpoint for authentication which would accept user/password and return the token in JSON format. For most Jenkins pages, the JSON API equivalent is found by simply appending /api/json to the URL, however `/me/configure/api/json` just throws a 404 at me. Does anyone know if there's such a way? All the docs I've found so far just tells you to go to the /me/configure webpage and look it up manually, which doesn't really make sense for a client wanting to pass along authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins user API tokens are not exposed via the API.

I would just take the API token once manually from Jenkins and hardcode that (rather than hardcoding your password), since the API token never changes unless you explicitly reset it.

Alternatively, you could authenticate with your username and password and store the resulting value from the `Set-Cookie` header.  Sending the cookie value in subsequent API calls would work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, if I want to make Jenkins API calls on behalf of end-users accessing my service, then it makes no sense to fetch the token manually, as it would need to be fetched for each individual user calling my API. However, an alternative approach might be to make all Jenkins API calls on behalf of a single dedicated "service user" as opposed to on behalf of end-users.